# Unable to run three.js example on apache tomcat 6

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am using eclipse to develop a web application.
I want to run my own 3d model made from sketchup and came accross this: http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Model.html and
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/porting-3d-graphics-to-the-web-webgl-intro-part-2/
. The models runs fine on my Chrome browser Version 24.0.1312.52.
However, when i try to deploy any of them locally on my apache tomcat 6.0, it does not appear at all. I have made sure that references to files like three.js and android.js are correct. Is there a server configuration somewhere? Am i missing something?

Comment: Please post some more details. How do you deploy them? How did you test it without Tomcat? Is there any difference between the source in the page deployed and the one that works?

Comment: I have apache tomcat 6 installed as a server on eclipse. I run it by clicking on the run button and selecting the server to run on. No, there is no difference in the source, which is what is puzzling me.

Comment: I have noticed that when i view source on my browser, the server is unable to access the three.js file, although the link is correct and the file is there. Im building on a dynamic web project on java ee, perhaps im not putting the three.js file where it's supposed to?

Comment: When you're deploying on Tomcat via eclipse, sometimes the resources in the war don't get deployed to the target folder. Check that the three.js file is actually being copied there. You can see where the project is being deployed in the project properties.

Comment: Glad to help. :) I've posted my comment as an answer, please mark it as accepted so the question doesn't show up as unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're deploying on Tomcat via Eclipse, sometimes the resources in the war don't get deployed to the target folder. Check that the `three.js` file is actually being copied there. You can see where the project is being deployed in the project properties.